# How should I declare this operator overload?

Tags: c++

I need to multiply a `const Vector` by an `int`, but I have to declare the overload as a non-member function and not as a method or it will not compile; how would I write the overload as a method?

```
namespace N
{
    class Vector {
    public:
        double x, y, z;

        Vector( );
        Vector(double x, double y = 0, double z = 0);

        Vector operator*(double k);
        //friend Vector operator*(const Vector u, double k);
    };
}

namespace N
{
    Vector::Vector( )
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }

    // Creates a vector with initial Cartesian components.
    //
    Vector::Vector(double x, double y, double z) :
        x(x),
        y(y),
        z(z)
    {
    }

    // Allows multiplying a vector by a scalar.
    //
    Vector Vector::operator*(double k)
    {
        Vector scaled;
        scaled.x = x * k;
        scaled.y = y * k;
        scaled.z = z * k;
        return scaled;
    }

    // Allows multiplying a vector by a scalar.
    //
    /*Vector operator*(const Vector u, double k)
    {
        return Vector(u.x * k, u.y * k, u.z * k);
    }*/
}



const N::Vector A(3, 4);
const N::Vector B(4, 3);

int main( )
{
    N::Vector resulting = A * 3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must declare it as a `const` method.

Comment: It might be better to have a nonmember operator as well to make the multiplication commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a member, simply change the code to

```
 Vector operator*(double k) const;
```

and in the definition

```
 Vector Vector::operator*(double k) const ...
```

As top-level:

```
friend Vector operator*(const Vector& u, double k);
```

and

```
Vector operator*(const Vector& u, double k)
{
    return Vector(u.x * k, u.y * k, u.z * k);
}
```